# Tiny MCE is working fine for firefox but not working in the chrome

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

i'm working on a project and i'm using Tiny MCE editor and i'm getting this kind of result on firefox
[firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yyqre.png) 
and on chrome i'm getting this kind of result
[chrome result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tI9hL.png)

So anyone can help me on this kind of issue

Comment: what is not working ? any error stack trace ?

Comment: i wanna display list items on center with bullet points on chrome while firefox is working fine with it

Comment: seems to be a CSS issue, not related to Tiny MCE, please post some source code so we can help

Comment: https://ibb.co/tHc9jsJ - check this link, data is coming from backend and this code is responsible for rendering data into frontend